# Param JSDOC en clases personalizadas Ecmascript 8

Tags: javascript, nodejs, jsdoc

Estoy documentando el codigo de javascript en visual studio code usandolo en NodeJS y me encuentro con el problema de hacer referencia de una clase personalizada dentro de otra usando JSDOC para el tema de parametros

Explico tengo 2 clases personalizadas:

Clase A - MyClassA.js

```
/**
  * MyClassA
  * @class
  */
class MyClassA {
    /**
      * @param {number} param1
      * @param {number} param2
      */
    constructor(param1, param2) {
        this.param1=param1
        this.param2=param2
    }

    myMetodo() {
        //doSomething
    }


}

module.exports = MyClassA
```

Clase B - MyClassB.js

```
/**
  * MyClassB
  * @class
  */
class MyClassB {
    /**
      * @param {MyClassA}
      * @param {number} param2
      */
    constructor(param1, param2) {
        this.param1=param1
        this.param2=param2
    }

    myMetodo() {            
        //doSomething
    }

}

module.exports = MyClassB
```

Pero no encuentro la forma de que JSDOC vincule lo vincule correctamente como para usar los metodos del archivo MyClassA.js en el archivo MyClassB.js

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar qué resultados buscas y qué resultados obtienes actualmente?

Comment: Buenas, después de buscar soluciones. Encontre la respuesta y ya lo publique como primera respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Solucion encontrada en link**: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23692

Simplemente para obtener una referencia de una clase en otra clase en diferentes archivos JS usando solo jsdoc use:

```
/** @typedef {import('./myClassA')} myClassA*/
```

Este se declara en donde lo quieres importar o necesites:

```
/** @typedef {import('./myClassA')} myClassA*/
/**
  * MyClassB
  * @class
  */
class MyClassB {
    /**
      * @param {MyClassA} param1
      * @param {number} param2
      */
    constructor(param1, param2) {
        this.param1=param1
        this.param2=param2
    }

    myMetodo() {            
        //doSomething
    }

}

module.exports = MyClassB
```

Esto soluciona el problema de ESLINT y su mensaje **no-unused-vars** cuando solo importamos archivos JS para referenciar el tipo en otros archivos.